# Calculate Mean, SD, and replace values in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, mean, standard-deviation

I have the above data frame, Date&Time with corresponding signal value.

1. I need to replace all the positive value with 0
2. Once replaced, `for every 60 seconds`, I need to calculate `mean` and `Std dev` and replace the value with mean which deviating a lot.

**For example, for the first 60 seconds, if the value at 2017-08-23 07:49:58 is deviating more from SD, then it should be replaced by mean. That means "59" should be replaced by mean**

```
     date-time             RSSI
    2017-08-23 07:49:38    -68
    2017-08-23 07:49:48    -69
    2017-08-23 07:49:58    -59
    2017-08-23 07:50:08    -65
    2017-08-23 07:50:18     127
    2017-08-23 07:50:28    -74
    2017-08-23 07:50:38     127
    2017-08-23 07:50:48    -74
    2017-08-23 07:50:58     127
    2017-08-23 07:51:08    -74
    2017-08-23 07:51:18    -65
    2017-08-23 07:51:28     127
    2017-08-23 07:51:38    -59
    2017-08-23 07:51:48    -62
    2017-08-23 07:51:58    -57
```

Expected output:

Output 1:

```
  date-time              RSSI
  2017-08-23 07:49:38   -68
  2017-08-23 07:49:48   -69
  2017-08-23 07:49:58   -59
  2017-08-23 07:50:08   -65
  2017-08-23 07:50:18    0
```

Output 2:

```
  date-time              RSSI
  2017-08-23 07:49:38   -68
  2017-08-23 07:49:48   -69
  2017-08-23 07:49:58   **-62**
  2017-08-23 07:50:08   -65
  2017-08-23 07:50:18   **-62**
```

Here `-62 is mean and its replaced`

Comment: what do you mean by "is deviating more from SD"?

Comment: When working with Date and time variables, it is especially helpful to provide your example data using `dput`. This allows us to cut and paste the data, and also helps us diagnose some potential issues that are common in such questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use for loops in R. Try and use vectored solutions and if you need performance usually the package data.table is what you want.

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table("date-time"=c(as.POSIXct(c("2017-08-23 07:49:38", "2017-08-23 07:49:48", "2017-08-23 07:49:58", "2017-08-23 07:50:08", "2017-08-23 07:50:18", "2017-08-23 07:50:28" ))), RSSI=c(-68, -69, -59, -65, 127, -74))

dt[RSSI > 0 , RSSI:=NA] #replacing positive ones with NA
print(dt)
dt[ , minute:=floor(as.numeric(`date-time`)/60)] # calculate for each time in which minute it belongs
# calculate mean and standard deviation per group
dt[ , c("mean", "stdev") := list(mean(RSSI, na.rm=TRUE), sd(RSSI, na.rm=TRUE)), by = minute] #ignoring the NA outliers
dt[ abs(RSSI - mean) > stdev  | is.na(RSSI), RSSI:=round(mean)] #round should return an integer
print(dt)
```

The solution you want should look similar to this.
Reading a csv with data.table works best with the function fread.

Comment: It is throwing an error. Is there a different way to read CSV through data.table?

Comment: Thanks, but the minute column is throwing warning, and all the values are NA

Comment: probably because your column date-time is a string and not a date-time object. Try dt[ , `date-time` := as.POSIXct(`date-time`)]. If this is slow use fasttime::fastPOSIXct().

Comment: It is not converting, it is still a character

Comment: There is warning message :

"In `[.data.table`(d, RSSI < mean - 2 * stdev, `:=`(RSSI, mean)) :
  Coerced 'double' RHS to 'integer' to match the column's type; may have truncated precision. Either change the target column to 'double' first (by creating a new 'double' vector length 1210 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'integer' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please."

Comment: I tried to change the datatype to int, still throwing the same warning. And I need the value to be replaced in RSSI